# What kind of signal modulation is more resistant to jamming?

Tags: noise, radio, spread-spectrum, interference, electronic-warfare

I've understood that spread-spectrum type of modulations are more resistant to narrow band jamming, for obvious reasons. What is less obvious is why someone would try to jam for example a cellular phone, GPS or ADS-B (Mode S) transmitter using a narrow-band jammer? (Whatever "narrow" or "wide" means in this context?)

What are the criteria and essential details for a jamming resistant modulation?

---

**EDIT**:

I have since understood quite a bit more about this topic. A wide-band jammer would spread all its energy over the entire spectrum of frequencies it tries to cover. This is extremely energy consuming and thus due to the inverse-square relation for radiation, you quickly loose energy with distance, so narrow-band beam formed jamming is preferred. However, narrow band jamming is weaker since certain frequency hopping methods can be applied to foil the jamming.

Comment: Would appreciate if someone could add `jamming` and `interference` to the TAG pool.

Comment: The short answer is that designing wideband transmitters is very hard.

Comment: @MBaz Wideband transmitters are [very easy to design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spark-gap_transmitter). But I dare say you mean legal ones. :-)

Comment: @PeterK. True :)  But I'd counter that designing a spark-gap transmitter that generates a large frequency and reaches more than a couple km is still very hard. Do you know what's the maximum frequency reached by a spark gap? I thought it was a few tens of MHz at best.

Comment: @MBaz Not sure about the frequency, but [this ARRL paper](http://www.arrl.org/files/file/History/History%20of%20QST%20Volume%201%20-%20Technology/Kennedy%20N4GG.pdf) quotes a range of 75 to 100 miles in 1905, which isn't too shabby. They say "very broad range of frequencies" but no figures.

Comment: @PeterK. Indeed -- but with an antenna 60m high and a gap voltage of several tens of thousands of volts, it doesn't fit my definition of "easy" :)  I seem to recall that Marconi's transmitter operated at a center frequency of 1.2 MHz.

Comment: The ability to compute a fire control solution of a jammer?